# javascript color picker

Tags: javascript, colors, color-picker

If you are using Gmail, you know that you can change the color of the labels. There are not too many color options, and I'd like to have something like that in my web app too. Even a `<select>` with some colors will be great. jQuery ColorPicker offers to many colors to choose from, and I don't need that.

Do you know something similar with Gmail label color chooser?

Comment: I've made a lightweight simple one [color-picker](https://github.com/yairEO/color-picker) in vanila-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [Really Simple Color Picker](http://laktek.com/2008/10/27/really-simple-color-picker-in-jquery/)? ([Demo](http://laktek.com/samples/color_picker/demo.html))

Comment: updated demo link: [here](http://laktek.github.io/really-simple-color-picker/demo.html)

Answer (score 3):

I've developed a simple color picker based on HTML `<select>`: [jquery-simplecolorpicker](https://github.com/tkrotoff/jquery-simplecolorpicker)

Inline mode:

[image: inline]

Picker mode:

[image: picker]

Online demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/VVclW0?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest and cleanest color picking process. Only using HTML.

```html
<input type="color" name="option_color" value="#DCEBD8" list="colors" style="height: 35px;width:60px">
<datalist id="colors">
    <option>#DDDDDD</option>
    <option>#F7D1D0</option>
    <option>#DCEBD8</option>
    <option>#D2E4EB</option>
    <option>#F7F0C5</option>
    <option>#E1D8ED</option>
    <option>#FFD5C2</option>
    <option>#D1F3EC</option>
    <option>#658CBB</option>
    <option>#e0c9bf</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check this also

[color picker and samples](http://jscolor.com/try.php)

Answer (score 0):

See my cross browser compatible [Color Selector](https://github.com/anhr/ColorSelector) (color picker). You can use my Color Selector instead of <input type="color"> if you want open your web page in an old web browser, that does not supports HTML5,
        for example IE6.

```html
<!--<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd">-->
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Color Selector</title>
 <meta name="author" content="Andrej Hristoliubov anhr@mail.ru">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/anhr/ColorSelector/master/ColorSelector.css" type="text/css">  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/anhr/ColorSelector/master/Common.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/anhr/ColorSelector/master/ColorSelector.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
 
 <p>
 Your browser does not supports HTML5 if you do not see the HTML5 color selector here: <input type="color">
 Instead you see a text input field.
 </p>
 <hr>
 My Color Selectors:
 <p>
  <input id="colorSelector1">
  <script>
   colorSelector.Create("black", function(selectedColor){
     consoleLog("selectedColor = " + selectedColor);
     var elementSelectedColor = document.getElementById("SelectedColor1")
     //elementSelectedColor.innerText = selectedColor;//Uncompatible with FireFox
     elementSelectedColor.innerHTML = selectedColor;
     elementSelectedColor.style.background = selectedColor;
     elementSelectedColor.style.color = invertHex(colourNameToHex(selectedColor));
    }
    , "colorSelector1"
   );
  </script>
  Selected color: <span id="SelectedColor1"></span>
 </p>
 <p>
  <input id="colorSelector2">
  <script>
   colorSelector.Create("#ffffff", function(selectedColor){
     consoleLog("selectedColor = " + selectedColor);
     var elementSelectedColor = document.getElementById("SelectedColor2")
     //elementSelectedColor.innerText = selectedColor;//Uncompatible with FireFox
     elementSelectedColor.innerHTML = selectedColor;
     elementSelectedColor.style.background = selectedColor;
     elementSelectedColor.style.color = invertHex(colourNameToHex(selectedColor));
    }
    , "colorSelector2"
   );
  </script>
  Selected color: <span id="SelectedColor2"></span>
 </p>
 <hr>
 Have a job for me? Please read <a href='../AboutMe/' target="_blank">About Me</a>.
</body>
</html>
```

Also see my example of [Color Selector](https://anhr.github.io/ColorSelector/)